# Intermittent Access Violation through __crtFlsGetValue

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio, crt

I am facing the Access violation intermittently in function `__crtFlsGetValue()` when it calls `(*pfFlsGetValue)(dwFlsIndex)`. The functions is part of windows provided source code file winapisupp.c. Access violation occurs after running application successfully for nearly 24 hours.

1. I generated my set of c based static libraries with VS2013 in Windows 10 OS. Later, The application has been built with these static libraries. CRT library is statically linked with this application. The application is also build with VS2013 on windows 10 machine.
2. Application keeps calling `sprintf` standard call in continuous loop after interval of 1 minute. `sprintf` internally calls windows provided function `__crtFlsGetValue()`.
3. On successful processing,  `(*pfFlsGetValue)` function pointer ,inside `__crtFlsGetValue()`, successfully points to `kernel32.dll!FlsGetValueStub`. But intermittently after 24 hours `(*pfFlsGetValue)` gets pointer to some other arbitrary address and which throws access violation. Following is the stack trace captured for same :-
   [image]
4. The application main thread spawns two more threads. `sprintf` is called in one of the spawned thread.

Please assist me in finding the root cause behind the issue.